# What does the type "char (&(...)) [2]" mean?

Tags: c++

I came across the following code:

`char (&f(...))[2];`

I checked the type of it (using typeid and c++filt) and got:

`char (&(...)) [2]`

But I can't make sense of this type. The [2] is the part that throws me off. Without it, I can replicate the type in a function definition, for example:

`char (&f(...))`

f is of the same type as h in (at least from the output of typeid + c++filt):

`char& h(...)`

Comment: Please post the full context in which this code appears.

Comment: isnt it reference to array of 2 functions returning char and taking C-style elipse?

Comment: It's a function returning a reference to an array of two characters. The second one (`char (&f(...))`) is a function returning a reference to a character. The outer parenthesis are superfluous in the second case and in both cases `...` is a C variadic argument pack.

Comment: @0x499602D2: I believe that's the correct answer.  Normally I'd suggest that people just use http://cdecl.org, but I don't know if an equivalent exists for C++.

Comment: Downvote for what exactly? If you check it, it is kind of obnoxious syntax, so I dont see anything wrong on him asking

Comment: @0x499602D2: Can you please show a function declaration that would have the same type as f in   `char (&f(...))[2];` ? I tried `char[2]& h(...);` , but it doesn't compile.

Comment: @dcmm88 I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a function declaration that has varying number of parameters and returns a reference to a character array of two elements.

It could be declared simpler by using a typedef. For example

```
typedef char char_array[2];

char_array & f( ... );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [cdecl](http://cdecl.org/) and substitute an arbitrary type for the ellipse, such as `int`:

```
char (&f(int)) [2]
```

Leads to

> declare `f` as function (`int`) returning reference to array 2 of `char`  […]

Substitute back and you have your declaration in words.

Answer (score 2):

```
char (&f(...))[2];
```

This is the declaration of a function returning a reference to an array of two characters. The parenthesis are needed for this to be syntactically correct. Otherwise the `&` will bind to `char` and there will be a syntax error because of `[2]` being meaningless.

The syntax can be decomposed with a type alias. For example:

```
using array_ref = char (&)[2];
array_ref f(...);
```

The reason for returning a reference to an array rather than an actual array is because of the fact that arrays cannot be returned from functions. It's impossible. You can only return references or pointers to arrays, just like functions.

In all examples, `...` is a C [variadic argument pack](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_argments).

---

The only places where I've seen this kind of syntax is where it's being used as part of function overload resolution for [SFINAE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae). Usually this function accompanies an overload of the same name that uses template substitution to check an attribute of a given type. If a substitution failure occurs the second overload (the one that takes a variadic pack) is chosen as the fallback. Its return type is what differentiates success or failure.

For example, here's trait class that checks if a type has a member function `f()`:

```
template <typename T>
struct has_f
{
private:
    using true_type  = char (&)[1];
    using false_type = char (&)[2];

    template <typename U>
    static decltype(std::declval<U>().f(), true_type()) f(int);

    template <typename>
    static false_type f(...);
public:
    static constexpr bool value = sizeof(check<T>(0)) == 1;
};
```

As you can see, if `T` has a member function `f()`, then the size of the type returned will be `1`, otherwise `2`. `true_type` and `false_type` are largely superseded by the standard traits classes `std::true_type` and `std::false_type` these days, but this is simply an example to illustrate its use.